# Magento admin display old version after upgrade Magento 2.2.5 to 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1

After upgrade Magento 2.2.5 to Magento 2.3.1, Magento admin panel still display the old version that is 2.2.5
Updgration done successfully but admin does not display new version.

Comment: Have you checked in your terminal what version does it say?

Comment: how exactly did you perform the upgrade? `Updgration done successfully` I doubt this. what leads you to this assumption?

Comment: when run deploys command then I can see it is upgraded. I have upgrade version by the composer and follow the instruction from this link https://blog.magestore.com/upgrade-magento-2-3/#a3

Answer (score 0):

Check your composer.json file in the magento root, for some reason magento admin gets the version that is shown in the footer from the composer.json

Comment: Yes, it was showing old version in composer.json then I have updated it but still admin display old version.